# PHP mysql query is not working with multiple "AND" operators

Tags: php, mysql

here is my query which is not working

```
SELECT p.pID 
  FROM CommunityStoreProducts p  
  JOIN CommunityStoreProductAttributeValues pav 
    ON p.pID = pav.PID 
 WHERE (
      (pav.akID = 62) 
   AND (pav.avID = 12313)
      ) 
   AND (
      (pav.akID = 64) 
   AND (pav.avID = 12315)
     ) 
   AND (
      (pav.akID = 65) 
   AND (pav.avID = 12316)
      )
```

and i also tried by diving the query like this :

```
SELECT p.pID FROM CommunityStoreProducts p INNER JOIN CommunityStoreProductAttributeValues pav ON p.pID = pav.PID WHERE (pav.akID = 62) AND (pav.avID = 12313)

SELECT p.pID FROM CommunityStoreProducts p INNER JOIN CommunityStoreProductAttributeValues pav ON p.pID = pav.PID WHERE (pav.akID = 64) AND (pav.avID = 12315)

SELECT p.pID FROM CommunityStoreProducts p INNER JOIN CommunityStoreProductAttributeValues pav ON p.pID = pav.PID WHERE (pav.akID = 65) AND (pav.avID = 12316)
```

all 3 querys are working well and returning value. when we joining this 3 into 1 query which is not working.

FYI : 1 product satisfying all 3 conditions

is there any wrong in the first query ?

thanks.

Comment: what error is shown when you run the first query?

Comment: do you have any products that satisfy all 3 conditions?? basically it should be impossible

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that you will get a row where `pav.akID` is 62 AND 64 AND 65 in the same row.

Comment: maybe it should've been `OR` instead of `AND`. Just saying, because the possibility of `pav.avID` and `pav.akID` having those values at the same time is low

Comment: If you are looking to fetch all data of this 3 queries, then you should use `OR` like `SELECT p.pID FROM CommunityStoreProducts p INNER JOIN CommunityStoreProductAttributeValues pav ON p.pID = pav.PID WHERE ((pav.akID = 62) AND (pav.avID = 12313)) OR ((pav.akID = 64) AND (pav.avID = 12315)) OR ((pav.akID = 65) AND (pav.avID = 12316))`

Comment: As a developer, saying `it does not work` is highly vague and not very professional.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any syntax errors regarding this query, however it will not return any value. There cannot be a record that has  `akID` equal to 62, 64 and 65 at the same time. If you wanted to return all such records, use `OR` operator:

```
SELECT p.pID FROM CommunityStoreProducts p
   INNER JOIN CommunityStoreProductAttributeValues pav
      ON p.pID = pav.PID
      WHERE pav.akID = 62 AND pav.avID = 12313
         OR pav.akID = 64 AND pav.avID = 12315
         OR pav.akID = 65 AND pav.avID = 12316
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use multiple "OR", you can replace them by "IN" condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.pID FROM CommunityStoreProducts p INNER JOIN 
CommunityStoreProductAttributeValues pav ON p.pID = pav.PID WHERE 
((pav.akID = 62) AND (pav.avID = 12313)) 
OR
((pav.akID = 64) AND (pav.avID = 12315)) 
OR 
((pav.akID = 65) AND (pav.avID = 12316))
```

Whenever you perform operation on same field with multiple condition, use OR instead of AND.

Answer (score 1):

i am working with a very complex product filter so i can't use "IN" or "OR" operator. Now i am changed the query like this it's work for me

```
SELECT p.pID FROM CommunityStoreProducts p 
INNER JOIN CommunityStoreProductAttributeValues pav620 ON p.pID = pav620.PID 
INNER JOIN CommunityStoreProductAttributeValues pav640 ON p.pID = pav640.PID
INNER JOIN CommunityStoreProductAttributeValues pav650 ON p.pID = pav650.PID
WHERE ((pav620.akID = 62) AND (pav620.avID = 12313))
AND ((pav640.akID = 64) AND (pav640.avID = 12315))
AND ((pav650.akID = 65) AND (pav650.avID = 12316))
```

i don't know whether it is correct or not, but it worked for me.
Thanks guys for your response

Comment: There is no logic in your opening statement.

Comment: i know, but for my requirement i can't use the "OR" statement. Here i am searching for the products that satisfy all 3 conditions. so i joined the same table with different alias. is it possible in other way ?